# Como concatenar uma String invocada de um arquivo xml com uma variável?

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

No Android Studio, estou tentando concatenar uma String que guardei num arquivo xml (strings.xml) com uma variável float da seguinte maneira:

`gas.setText(String.format("%s %s", R.string.gasoline_mod, value));`

A string guardada está da seguinte maneira:

`<string name="gasoline_mod">Gasoline: $</string>`

Porém, ao testar a aplicação, ao invés de aparecer a String guardada no xml, aparece um numero inteiro de 11 dígitos, seguido da variável float que, ao que parece, foi corretamente invocada. Existe alguma outra forma de invocar a String ou estou errando a sintaxe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para a aplicação acessar o valor da string, use o seguinte método:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

Ou seja, no seu código, altere o primeiro parâmetro:

```
gas.setText(String.format("%s %s", getString(R.string.gasoline_mod), value));
```

**NOTA**: Você diz que quer concatenar com uma variável `float`. Eu acredito que esse seja a sua variável `value`. Se for isso mesmo, o seu `String.format` está errado.

Segue tabela do pattern:

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Char  | Applies to                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
| %s    | string                                            |
| %d    | inteiros: byte, short, int, long, biting          |
| %e    | ponto flutuante (float) mas no formato científico |
| %d    | ponto flutuante                                   |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Ou seja, sua linha final deveria ser algo assim:

```
gas.setText(String.format("%s %d", getString(R.string.gasoline_mod), value));
```

Comment: Brother, gostaria primeiramente de agradecer pela atenção. Consegui fazer o código funcionar, porém tive que deixar a float como %s porque ao colocar como %d ela crashava.
Mas muito obrigado mesmo, salvou minha vida aqui.

Comment: Olá Thiago. Ok. Sem problemas. Aceite a pergunta se te ajudou ou vota positivo.